# Hex Cannot Be Found on Dockerized Phoenix App when running on Drone

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework, drone.io

So I currently have a setup wherein I deploy my dockerized Phoenix application to run tests on a self hosted Drone server. Currently the issue arises that no matter what Dockerfile I use(currently alpine-elixir-phoenix or a base elixir image with the following) which installs hex/rebar like below:

```
# Install Hex+Rebar
    RUN mix local.hex --force && \
    mix local.rebar --force
```

I receive the error upon booting in Drone,

`Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :phoenix`

I have found that by using an older version of alpine-elixir-phoenix:2.0 this issue does not come up which leads me to believe it may be something to do with hex/elixir having updated since then? Additionally if I run the commands to install hex and rebar within the container in Drone once it is instantiated there is no issue. I ran a `whoami` on the instantiated Drone container and the user is root if that makes a difference. Additionally if I run the container locally and run `mix hex.info`, it correctly states that hex is installed, however the issue is that on the Drone instantiated container this fails.

Example .drone.yml:

```
pipeline:
    backend_test:
    image: bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix
        commands:
            - cd api
            - apk update
            - apk add postgresql-client
            - MIX_ENV=test mix local.hex --force
            - MIX_ENV=test mix local.rebar --force
            - MIX_ENV=test mix deps.get
            - MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.create
            - MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.migrate
            - mix test
```

Example Docker File used(bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix) - https://github.com/bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix/blob/master/Dockerfile

where the same installation of local.hex and local.rebar occurs in the Dockerfile on lines 29 && 30. However upon instantiation of the container it is not found and therefore must be run again in the CMDs.

Furthermore I encountered this problem again but with `make` and `g++` not installing on alpine. I may be doing something incorrect but I cannot see where.

testbuild_env Dockerfile

```
FROM bitwalker/alpine-erlang:19.2.1b
ENV HOME=/opt/app/ TERM=xterm

# Install Elixir and basic build dependencies
RUN \
echo "@edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
apk update && \
apk --no-cache --update add \
  git make g++ curl \
  elixir@edge=1.4.2-r0 && \
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Install Hex+Rebar
RUN mix local.hex --force && \
mix local.rebar --force

ENV DOCKER_BUCKET test.docker.com
ENV DOCKER_VERSION 17.05.0-ce-rc1
ENV DOCKER_SHA256 4561742c2174c01ffd0679621b66d29f8a504240d79aa714f6c58348979d02c6

RUN set -x \
&& curl -fSL "https://${DOCKER_BUCKET}/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" -o docker.tgz \
&& echo "${DOCKER_SHA256} *docker.tgz" | sha256sum -c - \
&& tar -xzvf docker.tgz \
&& mv docker/* /usr/local/bin/ \
&& rmdir docker \
&& rm docker.tgz \
&& docker -v

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["sh"]
```

with the following .drone.yml

```
build:
    image: test_buildenv
    commands:
      - cd api
      - apk add make
      - apk add g++
      - MIX_ENV=test mix local.hex --force
      - MIX_ENV=test mix local.rebar --force
      - docker login --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD
      - mix docker.build # creates a release file after running a dockerfile.build image
      - mix docker.release # creates a minimalist image to run the release file that was just created
      - mix docker.publish # pushes newly created image to dokcerh
    volumes:
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I recommend providing the minimum yaml and dockerfile required to fully reproduce the issue. I also recommend reading http://readme.drone.io/usage/getting-started/#commands to explain how drone works. The user could definitely matter if Hex needs to be in the user PATH. Installing for user A doesn't necessarily mean it is available to user B. But this is just generic advice, since I do not know how hex / rebar install things.

Comment: Hey Brad thanks for the great work. So I ended up encountering the same issue with missing `make` and `g++` even though it was included within the dockerfile itself(and installed when the image was made as seen through the logs) however upon instantiation where make/g++ were needed the application failed out. Adding the `apk add make` and `apk add g++` lines makes the application compile fine...but I'm curious now for both make/g++ and hex...why installation within the dockerfile isn't enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Drone builds its own isolated working environment as an extra layer on top of your docker image, so the `ENV` settings in your `Dockerfile` are not available. You need to independently tell Drone the environment info so it knows where hex is installed.

I managed to get this working by setting `MIX_HOME` in the `.drone.yml` file:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir:1.8.1
RUN mix local.hex --force
```

.drone.yml:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: # built image of the above Dockerfile
    environment:
      MIX_HOME: /opt/app/.mix
    commands:
      - mix deps.get
```